# Only 2 intents work 'MAIN' and 'TEXT'

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying building my first app with `actions-on-google` / `google-assistant-sdk`, I wanted to start using 3 intents, the MAIN, respond to input TEXT, and `HELP` that the user can call anytime:

The `action.json` is:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "conversation_1"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
      }
    },

    {
      "description": "Help Intent",
      "name": "Help",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "conversation_1"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "app.StandardIntents.HELP",
        "trigger": {
           "queryPatterns": [
            "Help",
            "HELP",
            "help"
        ]
      }
    }
    }

  ],
  "conversations": {
    "conversation_1": {
      "name": "conversation_1",
      "url": "https://us-central1-sillytest-16570.cloudfunctions.net/sayNumber",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2      
    }
  }
}
```

The `index.js`:

```
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';

const ActionsSdkApp = require('actions-on-google').ActionsSdkApp;
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const NO_INPUTS = [
  'I didn\'t hear that.',
  'If you\'re still there, say that again.',
  'We can stop here. See you soon.'
];

exports.sayNumber = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new ActionsSdkApp({request, response});

  function mainIntent (app) {
    console.log('mainIntent');
    let inputPrompt = app.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>Hi! <break time="1"/> ' +
      'I can read out an ordinal like ' +
      '<say-as interpret-as="ordinal">123</say-as>. Say a number.</speak>', NO_INPUTS);
    app.ask(inputPrompt);
  }

  function rawInput (app) {
    console.log('rawInput');
    if (app.getRawInput() === 'bye') {
      app.tell('Goodbye!');
    } else {
      let inputPrompt = app.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>You said, <say-as interpret-as="ordinal">' +
        app.getRawInput() + '</say-as></speak>', NO_INPUTS);
      app.ask(inputPrompt);
    }
  }

  function helpHandler (app) {
    console.log('rawInput');
    app.ask('<speak>What kind of help do you need?</speak>');
  }

  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.MAIN, mainIntent);
  actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.TEXT, rawInput);
  actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.HELP, helpHandler);

  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

I pushed the `firebase` as:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

And pushed the Google Actions as:

```
gactions update --action_package action.json --project <YOUR_PROJECT_ID>
```

While testing the assistant [here](https://console.actions.google.com/project/sillytest-16570/simulatorcreate), it started in a good way, and repeat the number that I enter, wait for another number, and so on, but when I enter `help` it is terminated and not responding!

**UPDATE**

I tried the below, but did not work:

```
actionMap.set("app.StandardIntents.HELP", helpHandler);
```

I should expect the app to "What kind of help do you need?" when I enter/say "Help", but what happened is just re-writing it, same way it do with any other number.

[image]

Comment: why is helpHandler a `const` instead of a `function` like the other two?

Comment: I'm using it the ES6 style, it should be same meaning

Comment: @NickFelker To avoid any confusion, I re-wrote it the normal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-built-in Intents are only supported for the [first message in a conversation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#Input). After that, while you can use them for [speech biasing](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#ExpectedIntent), you will only get a built-in one such as the `TEXT` Intent.

Answer (score 1):

Your actionMap is looking for `app.StandardIntents.HELP` but it doesn't exist. You can view all of [the standard intents](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/assistant-app.js#L211) in the GitHub repo.

`app.StandardIntents.MAIN` returns another string which corresponds to "'actions.intent.MAIN'". It does not read your `action.json` and generate new intents. Thus, `app.StandardIntents.HELP` actually returns `undefined` and is never called.

Your map should use a string for your help intent since it is not available as a constant in the `app` object.

`actionMap.set("app.StandardIntents.HELP", helpHandler);`

This should resolve your issue. Let me know if it does not.

Comment: Did not work, I updated my code to math 100% the code I used, and provided print screen as well

Comment: Does it have to do with ordering? If `TEXT` is before `HELP`, it matches all text cases and would take precedence over help in the current case. Perhaps putting TEXT last would let it serve as a catch-all if the behavior isn't defined already.

Comment: :( Nothing changed